# Reducing the proof of the most elementary criterion of primality

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am interested in eliminating unnecessary steps in proving the following theorem:

If $n \ge 2$ is not a prime then $n$ is divisible by some prime $p$ such that $p \le \sqrt{n}$.

In the demonstration we can admit only two facts:

(1) The Least Integer Axiom (Well Ordering Principle);

(2) Every positive integer $n \ge 2$ is a prime or a product of primes.

The proof wich follows does not make direct use of (1) at any time.

Proof. If $n$ is not prime, it is of the form $n = ab$. If both $a$ and $b$ were greater than $\sqrt{n}$, we would have the contradiction $n > n$. So at least one of them is $\le \sqrt{n}$.

Without loss of generality, assume $a \le \sqrt{n}$.

If $a$ is prime, we're done.

If $a$ is not prime, it is a product of primes, by (2). Therefore, any prime factor $p$ of $a$ can be used, it is not necessary to take the smallest prime divisor of $a$.

The question is: is this proof that does not take "minimal divisors" correct?

-×-×-×-x-x-

Thanks for your answer, ConMan. I think we are now getting to the heart of the matter...

My assumptions are as follows:

A number is "prime" when it has no divisors other than 1 and the number itself (usual definition). Otherwise, if it has at least one divisor other than 1 and itself, it will assume the form $n = ab$, with $a$ and $b$ satisfying $1 < a < n$ and $1 < b < n$ (usual definition of a "composite" number).

So, there's no problem in the middle stages of the proof, I think.

The problem is possibly at the end. I wish I could say that any prime factor of

$a = pp'p''...$

serves our purposes, as any one of them satisfies

$p < a$ and $p | a$, and thus

$p < a \le \sqrt{n}$ and $p | n$.

So the question seems to be:

(i) I am obliged to use a proper axiom of theory, (1), to take one of the prime factors of $a$;

(ii) or I am obliged to use an axiom of the preferred foundational framework, Axiom of Choice, in this case...

Can't I just say that just taking any one of the prime factors of $a$ is enough to get the expected result?

Note: I just need to prove that $n$ is divisible by "some" prime $p \le \sqrt{n}$, I don't need to display this prime $p$. Right?

Comment: But $(2)$ is also proved by induction or WO, so you've simply moved its use elsewhere, not eliminated it.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for your observation. Proposition (2) is demonstrated using (1). I would just like to know if it is possible not to use (1) directly in the theorem above, that is, if I can avoid using the smallest prime factor of $a$...

Comment: You might be interested in more abstract settings like the Gaussian integers,  where numbers can be factored into primes but there is no total ordering of those numbers compatible with their addition and multiplication.

Comment: Thanks hardmath for your observation. it's nice to know that these creatures exist. I hope to get to this point soon...but actually my purpose here is very modest, I just can't understand why I'm obligated to refer to the smallest prime factor of $a$ if any of those factors could be used to reach the desired result...

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely admitting more than those two facts in your proof, and it's likely that there are steps where you need to prove their validity and/or improve their rigor if you haven't already. For example:

> If $n$ is not prime, it is of the form $n = ab$.

You've said that $n$ must be a product of primes, but does that mean it must have this kind of decomposition? Also, what if $a = 1$ and $b = n$?

> Therefore, any prime factor $p$ of $a$ can be used, it is not necessary to take the smallest prime divisor of $a$.

Are you sure that you can do this? If you don't apply Well Ordering (or more generally the Axiom of Choice), then can you actually select an arbitrary element of the prime divisors of $a$?